# Which HTTP status code to return if there is no data found from database in Rest Api call

Tags: java, rest

Well I have an microservice that is developed in spring boot and it call to an external database to fetch the results but now sometimes it does not able to fetch the results from external database as the database itself does not have data because there is a selective query fired from microservice to fetch the results from database , so in these conditions which correct http status code I should return , shall I return http status code 204. Please advise.

Comment: 404 : Does not exist

Comment: While you can follow standards, you can also return whatever you want. It's the client that's responsible for handling the code. For example, 200 with an empty body is fine. 204 also, or 404, or 500 if you always expect that endpoint to have data available

Comment: if it's /GET api by identifier-- then 404 and if it's Search /GET api then 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> shall I return http status code 204

My current thought is "probably not".  The specification of [204 No Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) includes this remark:

> The 204 response allows a server to indicate that the action has been successfully applied to the target resource, while implying that the user agent does not need to traverse away from its current "document view" (if any).

In cases where you have a GET request that returns an empty document, I prefer a [200 OK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) with [Content-Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2) 0.

The choice of 2xx vs 4xx comes down to what information you are including in the response-body: in the case of GET, if you are returning a representation of the resource, then you should be returning a 200.  If you are returning a document that describes an error, you should return one of the 4xx codes.

Which of these is the right answer will depend on your resource model.  It's perfectly reasonable for a search to return no results; in that case, returning a representation of an empty result set would call for a 200.  If the absence of data means (semantics) that the requested resource doesn't exist (or more precisely, doesn't have a current representation) then you should return a 404.

REST doesn't tell you which of these is "right" - it just gives us a common language for describing the alternative we have chosen in a way that general purpose components can understand what is going on.